# Assigning php variable values to html element

Tags: php, html

Im trying to assign the value of a php variable to a hidden element. But cant get it to work

Here's what Ive tried so far

Attempt 1:

```
echo '<input type="hidden" maxlength="100" name="value" id="val" value= "${myOb->content}"/>';
```

Attempt 2:

```
echo '<input type="hidden" maxlength="100" name="value" id="val" value= "<?php echo $myOb->content"/>';
```

On both counts . I just get the hard coded value ie. `${myOb->content}` or `<?php echo $myOb->content` in the html element rather than the server side variable. Any thoughts on what Im doing wrong?

Comment: PHP code cannot be nested within itself. `echo "<?php echo 'foo' ?>"` is going to print PHP code, not "foo". and even then, you're using the wrong type of quotes to allow embedding variables in text anyways.

Comment: @MarcB : Im relatively new to PHP . Any thoughts on what I should do, to get my expected result?

Comment: just like FreshPrince has below, minus the syntax error in the variable. it should be just `$myobj->whatever`. the `{}` brackets should only be used on variables within strings, e.g. `echo "{$foo}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
    <?php echo '<input type="hidden" maxlength=100 name="value" id="val" value="'.$myobj->foo.'">';
```

This works for me. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

When you use single quotes with `echo`, you're asking for the literal string value. You can try:

```
echo '<input type="hidden" maxlength="100" name="value" id="val" value= "' . ${myOb->content} . '"/>';
```

Comment: I get `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)` on that line. Any idea why that could be happening?

Comment: Try with $myObj->content

Answer (score 0):

If anyone need this in the future `"'.strval($recordId).'"` this worked for me.